# If $G$ is a locally compact group equipped with a Haar measure, then $L^{1}(G)$ is a Banach algebra with the convolution as the product operation.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convolution, topological-groups, haar-measure

I'm currently working on a research project based on John B. Conway's "A Course in Functional Analysis", specifically Fourier theory on locally compact groups. In his book, Conway claims that $L^{1}(G)$ has the structure of a Banach algebra with the convolution of functions as a product. Most of the properties follow immediately from standard results in measure theory. However, I'm struggling with the proof of the inequality $\Vert f\ast g\Vert\leq\Vert f\Vert\Vert g\Vert$. All the proofs I've seen at some point rely on a change in the order of integration, which is easily dealt with by making use of Fubini's theorem, but this only works when the space is $\sigma$-finite, which apparently isn't true for an arbitrary choice of $G$. It doesn't look like Conway implicitly assumes that this condition is satisfied since in later sections he does calculations involving discrete groups, which fail to satisfy $\sigma$-finiteness. So I'm guessing there must be a way around this. I saw on a similar thread that you can use a special case of Young's inequality, but after looking into it, the proof of this inequality is also dependent on the ability to change the order of integration.

On the other hand, since the product operation in Banach algebras is required to be associative, I have a similar problem when trying to prove this property for the convolution, since the standard proof of associativity of convolution also makes use of Fubini's theorem. So... what gives? Everything works out fine when the space is $\sigma$-finite, but seems to break down when we drop this hypothesis.

I'd be grateful if you could give me some advice on how to work around these.

Edit: I found in the same book that by proving that the set of all finite Borel Measures over $G$ is a Banach algebra with an adequate norm and product then if follows that $L^{1}(G)$ is a Banach algebra with the convolution as the product. So, that seems to solve the problem. However, out of curiosity, can we prove this directly, without resorting to a more general object?

Comment: I didn't really read this through, but maybe this helps? https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102968019

Comment: @JustDroppedIn I went through the book again and found a way to solve the issue I had but I'll check it out anyway. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask how you solved this issue?

Comment: You can check Gerald B. Folland's book: A course in Abstract Harmonic analysis. In section 2.3 (of the second edition), which is called "Interlude: Some Technicalities", this issue is dealt with directly. At the very beginning of the section Folland writes: *In the non-$\sigma$-compact case, Haar measure is not $\sigma$-finite, a fact that results in certain technical complications in the measure theory. The purpose of this section is to point these out and to explain why they are not serious.* It's a nice read.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn Basically, I was dumb and didn't preperly read an example given in an earlier section in which Conway outlines a way to give the set of finite Borel signed measures the structure of a Banach algebra by using the total variation as the norm and an adequate notion of convolution of measures as the product.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn He then uses this, together with the well-known fact that this set if measures is essentially the dual of $C_{0}(G)$, to realize $L^{1}(G)$ as a subalgebra of this set (with the convolution of functions as the product). In fact, since the identification preserves the norm, the fact that $L^{1}(G)$ is complete followed by all things considered before implies that it is in fact a Banach algebra.

Comment: @JustDroppedIn There were a couple of, if you will, "sketcky" details in the argument, mainly because Conway leaves them unexplained (or because my knowledge of functional analysis is a bit lacking). But it was good enough to convice me that it's a solid argument.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín Thank you both for your replies, I will keep them in mind.